# There is no such thing as magnetism?

Tags: electromagnetism

Here's an interesting "proof" that there is no such thing as magnetism. I know the answer but I love this so much I had to ask it here. It's a great way to confuse people!

As we all know, $$\nabla \cdot\vec{B} =0$$
Using the divergence theorem, we find $$ \iint_S \vec{B} \cdot \hat{n} \, dS = \iiint_V \nabla \cdot \vec{B} \, dV = 0$$
Since $\vec{B}$ has zero divergence, there exist a vector function $\vec{A}$ such that $$\vec{B} = \nabla \times \vec{A}$$
Combining the last two equations, we get $$\iint_S \hat{n} \cdot \nabla \times \vec{A} \, dS = 0$$
Applying Stokes' theorem, we find $$\oint_C \vec{A} \cdot \hat{t} \, ds = \iint_S \hat{n} \cdot \nabla \times \vec{A} \, dS = 0$$
Therefore, $\vec{A}$ is path independent and we can write $\vec{A} = \nabla \psi$ for some scalar function $\psi$.
Since the curl of the gradient of a function is zero, we arrive at:
$$\vec{B} = \nabla \times \nabla \psi = 0,$$
which means that all magnetic fields are zero, but that can't be!

**Can you see where we went wrong?**

Comment: Not advanced trick. What do you love about it?

Comment: This might only confuse people that don't realize you shouldn't throw away important information in the intermediate stages of a computation...

Comment: @AsphirDom With all due respect, I didn't ask for your opinion, as long as some people like it, it's interesting. Besides, no expert was born an expert, there are people who are still learning.

Comment: Don't take my comment personally. I am just curious to find out what we can LEARN from it?

Comment: I'm not taking it personally, I'm just saying that if you find it not advanced enough, not interesting or in any other way not good enough, you have the downvote button. 

Explicitly stating that you find it uninteresting is neither relevant nor constructive.

Comment: $$\int\!\!\!\!\!\int \!\!\!\!\!\!\! \bigcirc\text{?}$$

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Note that $\partial V=S$, so that

$$\tag{1} C~=~\partial S~=~\partial^2V~=~\emptyset$$

is the empty set. (Topologically, the boundary of a boundary is empty, or equivalently, the boundary operator $\partial^2=0$ squares to zero.) On the other hand, the circulation

$$\tag{2} \Gamma~=~\oint_{C=\emptyset}\vec{A}\cdot d\vec{r}~=~0$$

along the empty curve $C=\emptyset$ vanishes identically for *any* vector field $\vec{A}$. In particular, one can *not* conclude from (2) that the magnetic potential $\vec{A}$ should be a gradient field.

Comment: So, does all this comes from topology?

Comment: “the boundary of a boundary is zero!” - John Archibald Wheeler

Comment: @LarryHarson Yup! I suspect the OP has too little difficulty telling the difference between a doughnut and a coffee mug :) ! Or, more relevant to this question, the lack of homoemorphism between a closed sphere and a punctured one and the fallacious substitution of one for the other is what the fault is.

Answer (score 12):

Here's something from wikipedia:

"This classical Kelvin–Stokes theorem relates the surface integral of the curl of a vector field F over a surface Σ in Euclidean three-space to the line integral of the vector field over its ***boundary*** ∂Σ."

The catch in the statement of Stokes theorem is "boundary".So if V is a 3D volume,then it's boundary will be it's 2D surface which will be *closed as V is a 3D volume*.Now here's the catch,the boundary of a closed surface will not exist or will be null.(This has been pointed out mathematically by Qmechanic as $C=\partial S=\partial^2 V=\phi$).

*So in extremely simplified terms it's like concluding $a=0$ from $a \times 0=0$.*

Answer (score 3):

Adding a closed boundary $C$ around the volume generally splits $S$ into two surfaces $S_1$ and $S_2$ for which Stoke's theorem holds:

\begin{align*}
\oint_C \vec{A} \cdot \hat{t} \, ds &= \iint_{S_1} \hat{n} \cdot \nabla \times \vec{A} \, dS\tag{1}\\ 
\oint_C \vec{A} \cdot \hat{t} \, ds &= \iint_{S_2} \hat{n} \cdot \nabla \times \vec{A} \, dS\tag{2}
\end{align*}

I can use these two ways to show where your argument is wrong:

[image]

1. The left hand sides of (1) and (2) must be the negative of one another because the right hand sides sum to zero, and therefore
   $$\oint_C (\vec{A} - \vec{A}) \cdot \hat{t} \, ds = \iint_{S_1} \hat{n} \cdot \nabla \times \vec{A} \, dS + \iint_{S_2} \hat{n} \cdot \nabla \times \vec{A} \, dS = 0$$
   So you should have used $\vec{A}-\vec{A}$ in place of $\vec{A}$ in your application of Stokes theorem and concluding arguments, to give the trivial result $\vec B - \vec B = 0$
2. Let $S_1\rightarrow S,\,S_2\rightarrow 0$ as $C\rightarrow 0$.
   Then $(1)$ reduces to your application of Stokes theorem which reduces to $\vec{A}\cdot\vec 0 = 0$, making your following arguments irrelevant.

Comment: Nice surfaces. :)

Comment: @ArturodonJuan haha, thanks :) This was before I learned how to use Inkscape, so I used Microsoft word and their predefined 3d- shapes. Maybe that explains the lack of upvotes for my obviously correct answer ;)